# Tiny yolo on raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3b+

about the model you speak in this post:

[YOLO or SSD on raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62176/yolo-or-ssd-on-raspberry-pi/63084#63084?newreg=1d8e9663219d4227b0feb06eb3abf910)

did you retrain the tiny yolo from YAD2K? can you maybe share the implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome.  But the person who wrote the other question is very unlikely to see this as they have not been back to the site in almost a year.  If you would like to rephrase your question to address a more general audience, please do so.